# Command to Locate a File with a Specific Name on SSH

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, ssh

My goal is to write a command to locate a file called MABLE on my server. Then I need to craft this command to report no permission errors, but print out every other error.

Currently, I'm using

```
find / -name MABLE
```

After that, I'm putting in

```
ls -d mable
```

This is not working. Any better way write the command?

Comment: I'm confused; *MABLE* and *mable* are very different names, and a command searching for files is case-sensitive (so case matters!) unless you specifically tell it to ignore case (`-iname` for example).  Why are you using MABLE then mable - they'll be two different files.

Comment: if you intend to search for a file on the entire system, then `locate` is probably better siuted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Downloads folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348082/missing-downloads-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "process substitution" to pass the results of the find command to `grep`, in order to filter out the messages including `: Permission denied` as in:

```
find / -name MABLE 2> >(grep -v ': Permission denied')
```

`2>` captures the error output and redirects that to the `grep` command, to which that output appears as a file (an "unnamed pipe").